# API or a downloadable list of all IP ranges belonging to cloud providers

Tags: api, ip, cloud

Is there somewhere a downloadable list or an API for all IP ranges belonging to common cloud providers and/or cheap hosters like AWS, DigitalOcean, OVH, Rackspace, etc.

I mean something like this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IpRanges/

but in a bit more user friendly format than pulling it out of a .dll and updated a bit more often than once or twice a year.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace hosting IP ranges list
http://whoisthisip.com/isp-Rackspace+Hosting.php

AWS IP ranges list
http://www.whoisthisip.com/isp-Amazon+Web+Services.php

The list is yet to be updated for other service providers. You may wait for few more days for the DB to get updated with new ones.

Comment: Hm, I don't see a list, I just see counts per country, not really useful.